# How to stop multiple row highlighting

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 Jquery function. That is first function which allows to choose only one checkbox

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function () {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').not(this).prop('checked', false);
});
```

That is second function which allows to choose a checkbox by clicking a row.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.boekTable tr').click(function (event) {
        if (event.target.type !== 'checkbox') {
            $(':checkbox', this).trigger('click');
        }
    });
```

That is third function which higlights the selected row.

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function (e) {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $(this).closest('tr').addClass("highlight_row");
        } else {
            $(this).closest('tr').removeClass("highlight_row");
        }
    });
});
```

Problem: I select a row then third function highlights it and when i select another row, it keeps on highlighting till i click the highlighted row. How can i fix that? Should i use another function instead of closest? Thanx.

Comment: Have you tried `e.stopPropagation()` ?

Comment: Why you don't use radio to allow only one checked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a straight-forward change to make it perform the way you want...

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function (e) {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            // this will remove all highlights before adding a new one
            $(this).closest('table').find('tr').removeClass("highlight_row");
            $(this).closest('tr').addClass("highlight_row");
        } else {
            $(this).closest('tr').removeClass("highlight_row");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: @Atti you don't need the else now, see my answer :)

Comment: No worries - glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Update third to something like that:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function (e) {
    $(this).closest('table').find('tr').removeClass('highlight_row');

    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(this).closest('tr').addClass("highlight_row");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the highlight_row from the rest

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function (e) {
        $('tr').removeClass("highlight_row");
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $(this).closest('tr').addClass("highlight_row");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove class for other trs. You can use siblings function.

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function (e) {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $(this).closest('tr').addClass("highlight_row");
            $(this).closest('tr').siblings().removeClass("highlight_row");
        } else {
            $(this).closest('tr').removeClass("highlight_row");
        }
    });
});
```